# Where can I find Gnome-Classic themes?

Tags: 11.10, themes

Does anybody know where can I find themes for gnome 3 fallback mode?

I mean this session of gnome 3 :

[image]

Can anybody help me with this one,because I can't find any solutions.Pleaseeeeee!

Comment: Try GTK 3.x themes from [Gnome-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One source is [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org).

Not all GTK+3 themes are fallback compatible.  Generally, use the search option and restrict the search criteria for

- Type = GTK 3.x Theme/Style
- Description = fallback

Then look in detail at each of the search results for what issues are reported for using the theme with gnome-fallback.

## to install a theme

- make a themes folder: mkdir ~/.themes
- extract the zip file.
- move the extracted theme folder to the ./themes folder - for example `mv Zukini ~/.themes/`
- Use gnome-tweak-tool and change the theme

[image]

Most themes recommend you change the background properties for each panel to use the `panel.png` that comes with a theme.  As you can see in the image - I'm using the [Zukini theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Zukini?content=147431).