# Create new Gnome Classic theme and config system to offer all users

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes, gnome-classic

I'm trying to create **new Gnome Classic theme (gnome-session-fallback)** on Ubuntu Precise. I want to include it into `System Settings -> Background menu` to offer that configuration to all users.

I'm searching information related but all I find is related with Gnome shell or Unity.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a gtk3 theme (fallback compatible).

In the following [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96237/where-can-i-find-gnome-classic-themes), [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) explains how to search for gtk3 themes fallback compatibles.

I would recommend use **"Ambiance"** theme as template *(Fallback Compatible too)* to create your theme.

Here you have a useful [Article](http://funsurf-blog.blogspot.com/2012/06/when-you-make-gtk3-theme.html) about GTK3 theming.

### Article's quote

> Let's face it, you cannot a make GTK3 only theme. You have to provide
>   a GTK2 theme which matches the GTK3 theme. Otherwise there will be no
>   integration between GTK2 and GTK3 apps and it will look really bad.
>   And you may also provide a matching window theme, like metacity,
>   mutter, xfwm etc. GTK2 and metacity theming are a pain, but you have
>   to do it if you want people to use your theme.

### Info and tool about GTK themes

- [Basic Tutorial GTK3](http://worldofgnome.org/making-gtk3-themes-part-1-basics/)
- [Tutorial GTK2 Themes](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes)
- [Info About Gtk3 theming](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/theming.html)
- [GTK Theme Preferences](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/customize-gtk3-gtk2-theme-colors-using.html) *(This little tool allows anyone to change some basic elements of a GTK theme easily (both GTK2 and GTK3) with a simple interface.)*

### Adding theme to System Settings > Appearance list

To add a theme to the *System Setting > Appearance* you should to edit and recompile the **gnome-control-center** source. *(The theme's list is hardcoded)*

[image]

**NOTE:** *This example is in Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-control-center-3.4.2 to add the **MediterraneanDark** theme to the Appearance list.*

**1)** Download the tar.gz file of [MediterraneanNight Series](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=156782) to your Download directory.

**2)** Extract the tar.gz file and copy the theme to the */usr/share/themes* folder.
Open a Terminal and type:

- `cd ~/Downloads`
- `tar -xvzf MediterraneanNight-2.03.tar.gz`
- `sudo cp -R ~/Downloads/MediterraneanDark/ /usr/share/themes/`

**3)** Create and Edit the index.theme file for the MediterraneanDark theme.

- `sudo cp /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/index.theme /usr/share/themes/MediterraneanDark/`
- `sudo sed -i 's/Ambiance/MediterraneanDark/g' /usr/share/themes/MediterraneanDark/index.theme`

Content of the index.theme file:
[image]

**4)**  Install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

**5)** Install build dependencies.

- `sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-control-center`

**6)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src-center`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src-center`

**7)** Download the source code.

- `apt-get source gnome-control-center`

**8)** Edit the Source Code.

- `gedit gnome-control-center-3.4.2/panels/background/cc-background-panel.c`

Search for the lines **1232** and **1233** to edit them and add the theme.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

I changed from:

> static gchar *themes_id[] = { "Adwaita", "Ambiance", "Radiance",
>   "HighContrast", "HighContrastInverse" }; static gchar *themes_name[] =
>   { "Adwaita", "Ambiance", "Radiance", "High Contrast", "High Contrast
>   Inverse" };

To:

> static gchar *themes_id[] = { "Adwaita", "Ambiance", "Radiance",
>   "HighContrast", "HighContrastInverse", "MediterraneanDark" }; static
>   gchar *themes_name[] = { "Adwaita", "Ambiance", "Radiance", "High
>   Contrast", "High Contrast Inverse", "MediterraneanDark" };

**9)** Go to the gnome-control-center-3.4.2 folder to build the deb packages.

- `cd gnome-control-center-3.4.2/`
- `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`

**10)** Install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

**11)** Finally you can logout and Login to see the changes.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that can help me. I'll try and I give you feedback. It's curious that the Ubuntu logo that appears in the top panel dissapears.